# What's the difference between \AtBeginDocument and \AddToHook{env/document/begin}?

Tags: latex-base, hooks

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{\linespread{1}\fontsize{12bp}{23bp}\selectfont}
% \AddToHook{env/document/begin}{\linespread{1}\fontsize{12bp}{23bp}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

and it shows that `\AtBeginDocument` method works and the `\AddToHook{env/document/begin}` method doesn't. I don't know what's the difference between these two hooks. I'd appreciate it if you can offer any help.

Comment: see also texdoc lthooks I guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\begin{document}` runs `\normalsize` to set up the default font.

`\AtBeginDocument` is `\AddToHook{begindocument}` and happens after the `\normalsize`

`\AddToHook{env/document/begin}` happens before the main code of `\document` so before the `\normalsize`, so has no effect here.